# how to make space between 2 string in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

hi i want to ask if how i can put one line space in python 3.
i use this code:

```
#def space():
#print()
```

but when i want to print it there is a "none" that prints for me but i want just a line with nothing 
i.e i want to type :

```
"hi how are you :

iam fine"
```

i want to have the space between `"hi how are you "` and `"iam fine"` 
i give this to python3 :

```
print('hi how are you",space(),"iam fine")
```

but it will give me only:

```
 hi how are you None iam fine ..
```

what is the problem here? what dose this none means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what you want:

```
def space():
    return '\n'
```

`None` is what it sounds like, it's printing None because you're not giving `print()` any inputs

Comment: The `None` is the return value of the `space` function, it has nothing to do with the inputs to `print`.

Comment: this is what i get in python wen i use your code:                 >>> def space():
    return '\n'

                                                                      >>> space()
'\n'

Comment: @user1893221: Try the snippet you originally posted with the new function: `print("hi how are you", space(), "I am fine")`

Comment: i got it so now if i want more space like 3 lines between my strings i have to def angain by two return'\n' ?  i tried it its not working ...

Comment: ps: please upvote/choose answers on stack overflow if you got an answer to your question!

Answer (score 1):

`print()` happens immediately. If you want a **newline** then you need to return `'\n'` instead.

Comment: i see .. but i still have problem with it how do i have to return'\n' ?